# NameError: name 'player_score' is not defined - i'm not compleatly new but need assistance

Tags: python-3.x

```
import tkinter as sg
from random import randint
import time
t = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
comput = t[randint(0, 2)]
def comput_score():
    if comput == '1':
        comput = 'rock'
    if comput == '2':
        comput = 'paper'
    if comput == '3':
        comput = 'scissors'
print(comput)
def score():
    comput_score = 0
    player_score = 0
def end():
    pass
#rock = 0, paper = 1, scissors = 2
###### player = rock
def play():
    global player_score
    global comput_score
    player = input("Choose rock-paper-scissors(or end to end the game): ").lower()
    if player == "rock":
        if comput == "rock":
            print("Computer choose rock")
            print("TIE!")
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
        if comput == "paper":
            print("Computer choose paper")
            print("HA! Paper beats rock")
            comput_score = +1
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
        if comput == "scissors":
            print("Computer choose scissors")
            print("Awesome, You Won! rock beats scissors")
            player_score = +1
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
    ##### player = paper
    if player == "paper":
        if comput == "rock":
            print("Computer choose rock")
            print("Awesome, You Won! paper beats rock")
            player_score = +1
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
        if comput == "paper":
            print("Computer choose paper")
            print("TIE!")
        if comput == "scissors":
            print("Computer choose scissors")
            print("HA! Scissors beats paper")
            comput_score = +1
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
    ##### player = paper
    if player == "scissors":
        if comput == "rock":
            print("Computer choose rock")
            print("HA! Rock beats scissors")
            comput_score = +1
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
        if comput == "paper":
            print("Computer choose paper")
            print("Awesome, You Won! scissors beats paper")
            player_score = +1
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
        if comput == "scissors":
            print("Computer choose scissors")
            print("TIE!")
            print("you score: " + str(player_score))
            print("copmuter score: " + str(comput_score))
    if player == "end":
        end()
play()
end()
print("hiiii")
```

this is a game of rps I need help with it, I've only been coding in python for about a week or 2 so I don't know everything yet. I've haven't tried anything and am open to all suggestions.  please also add some suggestions for what i can do to make the code more neat or efficient, thank you.....................................................................

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that my issue is that after i build it i can go up to choosing rock paper or scissor and it shows who won or lost or tied but after that i get the message ---NameError: name 'player_score' is not defined ---

Comment: The error is for the variable name `player_score` that you have defined as global variable under your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 'player_score' in the 'score' function, but do not call this function. And in the 'score' function you need to define the 'player_score' as global

```
def score():
    global player_score
    player_score = 0
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!